# Plot the ellipse in Mathematica 12.0

Tags: plotting

`sols9[x_, a_] := y /. Solve[x^2/6 + (y - a)^2/3 == 1, y, Reals];
sols8[x_, a_] := y /. Solve[y == a x^2, y, Reals];
sols7[x_, a_] := y /. Solve[y == a x, y, Reals];
Manipulate[Show[{ContourPlot[sols9[x, a], {x, -14, 14}, {y, -14, 14}, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], Plot[sols8[x, a], {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> 10 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotStyle -> Magenta, AspectRatio -> Automatic],Plot[sols7[x, a], {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> 10 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},PlotStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> Automatic]}], {{a, 3}, -3, 3, 0.1}]`

*I tried it in a new Notebook, but it still failed.*

Answer (score 1):

Change the first argument in `Show[...]` to

```
ContourPlot[x^2/6 + (y - a)^2/3 == 1, {x, -14, 14}, {y, -14, 14}
```

[image]

The same result follows with

```
ContourPlot[{y == sols9[x, a][[1]], y == sols9[x, a][[2]]} , {x, -14,14}, {y, -14, 14}, Evaluated -> True]
```

Comment: Can you use something to replace the equation? In the Code I posted above, I used sols9. Can u write replace the equation while stile using "ContourPlot".

Comment: My answer is edited.

Comment: But the ellipse in not perfect. And it's not in the right shape!